# How to reuse C# code across multiple Godot-mono projects

Tags: c#, macos, godot

I have 1 godot_mono game **A**.
Now I would like to create additional game **B**.
Is there any example how I can reuse codebase from project **A** in the project **B**. Please pay attention codebase is not only C# code, it is C# code that uses `<Project Sdk="Godot.NET.Sdk/3.2.3">` and Scenes, images, sounds + other resources.
On top of all I use macos.

**EDIT** 
Copy paste way is not acceptable, because shared code is not in finite state itself, and will not be. I looking for some shared Lib, links or even shared game.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is have a shared `addons` in Godot and then symbolic link this `addons` directory into every game. I have a bat file I run when creating a new game which makes the symbolic link, so you're good to go.

The addons can be tools ie: custom nodes that appear in your new item view or just loose `.cs`, common scenes and common fonts / sounds, common methods you need, extensions etc.

```
Shared\addons
Games\Game1\addons << symbolic link
Games\Game2\addons << symbolic link
Games\OtherGame\addons << symbolic link
```

Answer (score 0):

Scripts and assets are just files within your game's project folder. If game **B** project contains *Godot.NET.Sdk/3.2.3*, you can just copy and paste files (scripts and assets) from game **A** to game **B**.

**EDIT**

After OP edited the question, this no longer answers it.

Comment: Copy paste way will work. But will lead to double efforts on both projects if shared code changed. And Once I have project 3, 4...

Comment: C# has a handy-dandy feature called NuGet packages. You could pack your shared code into those NuGets (and update during development). If privacy is concerned, just host a private NuGets repository.

Comment: this is much better solution.
The question is - I'm not experienced in C# enough to create NuGet package with dependency on `Godot.NET.Sdk/3.2.3`

Comment: There's NuGet for `Godot.NET.Sdk/3.2.3` (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Godot.NET.Sdk). This means, you can just pack project, including that NuGet in `.nuspec` file and it will be linked as dependency. For linking dependencies, check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#the-role-and-structure-of-the-nuspec-file

Answer (score 0):

When you compile C# in Godot, the generated binaries are in /.mono/temp/bin/Debug/.(dll/pdb)

When you export the project the dll is in assemblies folder of the .pck

In theory you could take these dlls and package them using nuget. This would be better than copy/pasting.

Of course this is not supported by Godot, and most likely you would have to write your own toolchain to automate this.